# What do the subindices $jkl...$ represent in the nonlinear polarization equation?

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics

After studying [this article on non-linear polarization](http://www.physics.ttk.pte.hu/files/TAMOP/FJ_Nonlinear_Optics/3_the_nonlinear_polarization.html#:%7E:text=In%20case%20of%20linear%20response%2C%20the%20polarization%20oscillates,the%20responses%20for%20centrosymmetric%20and%20non-centrosymmetric%20crystal%20structures), I have two main questions:

The first was which is the origin of $n$th order susceptibilities; this was mainly already answered by a previous thread on this site,
[Microscopic origin of non-linear optical effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/603510/microscopic-origin-of-non-linear-optical-effect).

My second question is the following:

How the subindices $jkl\ldots$ in the polarization equation,
$$
P_i(E) = \varepsilon_0 \left( 
\sum_j \chi_{ij}^{(1)}E_j
+\sum_{j,k} \chi_{ijk}^{(2)}E_jE_k
+\sum_{j,k,l} \chi_{ijkl}^{(3)}E_jE_kE_l
+\cdots
\right)
\qquad (i,j,k,l = x,y,z),
$$
arise in a system of $n$ oscillators? According to what I have understood, the $i$th index in equation gives us the polarization of $i$th oscillator that is subject to a total "mean" field $E_\mathrm{tot}$, which is the result of an applied incident field $E_\mathrm{inc}$ and the induced field $E_\mathrm{ind}$ that arise from every other point oscillator. Do the $jkl\ldots$ correspond to the $n-1$ directions of every other oscillator in respect to that $i$th oscillator?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 1):

As the equation you have quoted states explicitly, the indices $i,j,k,l,\ldots$ stand for the three Cartesian axis directions, $x$, $y$ and $z$. Both the polarization $\vec P = \vec P(\vec E)$ and the electric field $\vec E$ that causes it are vector quantities, and $P_i = \hat{\mathbf e}_i \cdot \vec P$ and $E_i = \hat{\mathbf e}_i \cdot \vec E$ are the components of the respective quantity along the axis $i$.

To be clear, they are *not* labeling individual microscopic emitters ("oscillators") within the medium.

For a medium which is [isotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy), in general, if you apply an electric field which is oscillating along (say) the $x$ axis, then the polarization of the medium must happen along that axis.

However, there are plenty of media which are not isotropic, such as e.g. crystalline samples. For these cases, applying a driving electric field along direction $j$ can also drive a response along $i$ (for any value of $i=x,y,z$).

This happens, of course, for nonlinear optics, but it is also the case in linear optics (i.e. if you discard all nonlinear terms with $\chi^{(n)}$ with $n\geq 2$, and you keep only the linear susceptibility $\chi^{(1)}_{ij}$), where the general name of this phenomenon is known as [birefringence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence), and it is the driving principle behind e.g. [quarter- and half-wave plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate).